# Different Result between Operating System in Malloc

Tags: c, windows, malloc, mingw

I try to create BFS like of tree. I made the tree and queue the child.

I've wrote the code in here https://github.com/cengek/CKDatastruct.

But strangely, when my friends who use Windows and MinGW to compile it it return error. It doesn't happen in OSX and and Linux.

My friend said it become error when I used malloc.

I don't know where the specific code that does the error but I think it's in here

this is the part where I put the child of tree into the queue

```
   while (isEmpty(antrianNodes) != 1) {

        //tampilkan isinya
        printf("%c,", antrianNodes.first->paket.s->c);

        simpul * now = antrianNodes.first->paket.s;

        simpul * nodePertama = now;


        //jika punya anak
        //masukkan child dari node alamat di queue ke dalam queue sekarang

        if(now->child != NULL){
            simpul * nowchild = now->child;

            //jika punya saudara
            if(nowchild->sibling != NULL){

                //looping memasukkan anak-anak
                while (nowchild->sibling != now->child) {
                    add(&antrianNodes, nowchild);
                    nowchild = nowchild->sibling;
                }
                //masukkan yang terakhir
                add(&antrianNodes, nowchild);
            }else{
                //tak punya saudara masukkan saja satu
                add(&antrianNodes, nowchild);
            }
        }

        del(&antrianNodes);
    }
```

and in here for adding the childs into the queue so I can process it. It does the print of the child.

```
void add(queue *Q, simpul *s){
elemen * baru = (elemen *) malloc(sizeof(elemen));
baru->paket.s = (simpul *) malloc(sizeof(simpul));
baru->paket.s = s;
baru->next = NULL;
if(isEmpty(*Q) == 1){
    (*Q).first = baru;
    (*Q).last = baru;

}else{
    (*Q).last->next = baru;
    (*Q).last = baru;
}

(*Q).jumlahElemen++;
```

}

I think it is the ordinary code of queue and tree.

Honestly I don't know where the exact part because it does strangely different in every operating system, i've try to compile it in ideone and give the correct result as this http://ideone.com/vVNOe

My friend said the error from windows is like this

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   main.exe
Application Version:    0.0.0.0
Application Timestamp:  4fa665b6
Fault Module Name:  main.exe
Fault Module Version:   0.0.0.0
Fault Module Timestamp: 4fa665b6
Exception Code: c0000005
Exception Offset:   000015e0
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
Locale ID:  1033
Additional Information 1:   0a9e
Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
Additional Information 3:   0a9e
Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
```

C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

Does every operating system do the different malloc? Or is it just my code that do the error?

Best Regards
giripp

Comment: You expect us to just go and read all your code? Why? Put the relevant portion here.

Comment: @Oleksi my friends do the screenshot and it said 
main.exe has stopped working
Windows can check online for solution to the problem

Comment: @littleadv thanks for your suggestion, I've put the code. I think that is the code that does the error, but I don't know exactly is that create the error or not

Comment: interesting comments in this source ... - that what kind of language?-)

Comment: @alk it's Indonesian, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the cause of your problem or not, but it might be.  In `add()` you allocate a new `simpul` and place that pointer into a `paket`, but then you immediately overwrite that pointer with the one passed as an argument to `add()`:

```
baru->paket.s = (simpul *) malloc(sizeof(simpul));
baru->paket.s = s;
```

But I'm not sure.

---

Also, your `makeTree()` function needs to initialize the `child` member of the root node:

```
baru->child=NULL;
```

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately the error still exist. I have put the details of error. I the some research and it said I use memory which is not allocated. But I don't know what kind of memory, I hope I could  see the memories :)

Comment: Oh well okay you put the last part for the answer, heheh, I'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

Oh my god, the answer is I forgot to make the `baru->child = NULL`.

That's the problem because computer thought the new child is not NULL. Maybe in Windows it create random memory address for new allocation and OSX or Linux automatically set it to be NULL.

Thanks guys for you which try to answer my question

Best Regards
Giri